# Python Datetime round timedelta to nearest biggest unit

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, formatting

I've been making a forum as a learning experience. I have a timestamp for every post, which I convert to a timedelta (how much time ago it was). I want to output the time like so:

```
If it's    <     1 minute                       display it in seconds
If it's    >=    1 minute   and    < 1 hour     display it in minutes
If it's    >=    1 hour     and    < 1 day      display it in hours
If it's    >=    1 day      and    < 1 week     display it in days
If it's    >=    1 week     and    < 1 month    display it in weeks
If it's    >=    1 month    and    < 1 year     display it in months
If it's    >=    1 year                         display it in years
```

What is the best way to do this in python and datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third-party library.  For example, [`readabledelta`](https://pypi.org/project/readabledelta/) is a `timedelta` subclass which prints human-readable.

```
>>> from readabledelta import readabledelta
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> print(readabledelta(timedelta(seconds=1)))
1 second
>>> print(readabledelta(timedelta(seconds=60)))
1 minute
>>> print(readabledelta(timedelta(seconds=60*60)))
1 hour
>>> print(readabledelta(timedelta(seconds=60*60*24)))
1 day
>>> print(readabledelta(timedelta(seconds=60*60*24*7)))
1 week
```

You can not easily use months or years, because the length of the unit is not well defined (a month could be 28-31 days, and a year could be 365-366 days).